# Opera breaks Favorite-Tags borders

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, opera

With the Opera browser, I noticed that the tags on the right panel are broken, when carriage return needs to be inserted.

[image: Broken Tag List on SuperUser]
[image: Broken Tag List on StackOverflow]

It does not happen with Firefox.

Comment: solution: do not use Opera :)

Comment: Opera is (mostly) a thing of sublime beauty, unappreciated by the world. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this behavior as of Opera 12.15 on OSX or Opera 24.0 on Windows.  This isn't a big surprise, though, because there have been about a trillion little css tweaks since 2011, as well as many overhauls.